# How to remove a substring matching a pattern in a specific position in bash?

Tags: string, bash, sed

In a bash script, I use a `$temp` variable containing several lines of text and I need to **remove the first character in all the lines that start with a space**.

I tried using sed:

`temp=$(sed 's/ //' <<< "$temp")`

but it removes the first space no matter where it is, so I end up with some words altogether.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this then:

```
temp=$(sed 's/^ //' <<< "$temp")
```

It will anchor the space to beginning of the line.